# Overriding QMainWindow methods in PyQt from QtCreator

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt-creator

I've got this GUI code which is generated by `pyuic5` with `-x` parameter. I have added some of my code to `Ui_LEDController` such as connecting to arduino through serial port. I want to achieve disconnecting Arduino while program is closed through `X`.
I know I have to override `QMainWindow` method `closeEvent()`, but I wonder what steps should I proceed to achieve this. I can't just create `class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow())` and then `LEDController = MyWindow()`, because I will not be able to access serial variable.
So basicly: should I not use this `Ui_LEDController` to set GUI items and instead of this create `class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow())` in which I would implement all of the GUI items and override `closeEvent()`?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_LEDController(object):
    def setupUi(self, LEDController):
        LEDController.setObjectName("LEDController")
        LEDController.resize(230, 160)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(LEDController.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        LEDController.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        LEDController.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(230, 160))
        LEDController.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(230, 160))
        # Lot of initializing
        LEDController.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.retranslateUi(LEDController)
        # Signals and Slots handlers
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LEDController)

    def retranslateUi(self, LEDController):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        LEDController.setWindowTitle(_translate("LEDController", "LEDController"))
        self.bright_label.setText(_translate("LEDController", "Brightness"))
        # Changing text in items


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    LEDController = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_LEDController()
    ui.setupUi(LEDController)
    LEDController.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two ways:

subclass both `QMainWindow` and `Ui_LEDController`

```
class MyWindowClass(QMainWindow, Ui_LEDController):
```

or subclass only `QMainWindow` with attribute `self.ui`

```
class MyWindowClass(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.ui = Ui_LEDController()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

and then use all variables of both classes

Comment: Great idea! Thanks. I have used second solution. :)